# Create a Microsoft Bot Project in .net Framework instead of .netcore?

Tags: .net-core, botframework, bots, direct-line-botframework

Whenever I create a basic bot project in Visual Studio using Microsoft Bot Framework V4 a project with .net core is being created. I want the bot project to be created/Implemented using .Net Framework.

How to create/Build Bot project(Microsoft Bot Framework V4) using .net framework?

Comment: "I want the bot project to be created/Implemented using .NetFramework. " : why?

Comment: I want to use Dynamics CRM sdk from the project directly which is not supported in .netcore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you can, Microsoft has a github repo containing all the code you need to see how things vary from different frameworks/languages.

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples

csharp_webapi is a .NET project, take a look!

Comment: To date this is still the only .NET Framework CoreBot template I've been able to come across; everything else seems to want v4 Framework bots to be .NET Core - or at least the templates.